# Anonymous Type Appears in both Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a linq query that populates the `GridView` on `Page_Load`. I have made a `for` loop of Characters for the alphabet. In the `.Command` of the `LinkButton` that populates the `LinkButton`, I am running a very similar query using the same parameters in the query and getting the below error.

> The type '<>f__AnonymousType2' exists in both 'ConcernContracts.dll' and 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'

```
void lnkCharacter_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var lbtn = (LinkButton)lbl_Alphabet.FindControl("lnkCharacter" + e.CommandArgument);
        var id = lbtn.Text;

        using (var db = new dbDataContext())
        {
            var query = from n in db.tbl_Providers
                        where ((n.provider_Name.StartsWith(id)) && (n.provider_Deleted == false))
                        select new
                        {
                            n.ProviderId,
                            n.provider_Name
                        };

            grd_Provider.DataSource = null;
            grd_Provider.DataSource = query;
            grd_Provider.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (SystemException ex) { }
}
```

The LoadGrid() is the same, but it doesn't use the `.StartsWith()` condition.
Do you have any Ideas how to solve the error?

The error doesn't throw an exception, but it doesn't populate the grid for either of the queries. The error was discovered in the following line: `grd_Provider.DataSource = query;`

Comment: Are the projects in the same solution?  Do they have the same namespace?

Comment: Rebuild, Clean, Build.

Comment: Yes they are in the same solution. The queries are on the same page.

Comment: Agree with previous, add a namespace - if this is a web project you might have to move the code to the app_code folder when you do this.
Also - just by the bym, I would remove the empty catch statement, that's not a good idea. If you catch errors, do something with them  - alert the user or at least log them somewhere etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your grid data source

```
grd_Provider.DataSource = query.ToList();
grd_Provider.DataBind();
```

or create List having two properties Provider Id and Name and bind that list from output
like this.

```
 List<Entities> abc=query.ToList();
 grd_Provider.DataSource =abc;
 grd_Provider.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion:

Your two similar queries are probably overlapping on that anonymous type you are selecting in the LINQ  query. On one and only one of the queries, change the select new to look like this:

```
select new
       {
         Id = n.ProviderId,
         Name = n.provider_Name
       };
```

If you do this, the anonymous types shouldn't conflict anymore, since the one you don't modify will use the default names.

Good luck, and I hope this helps!

Comment: I have made another grid on the page and tried to poulate that grid but it doesnt work either. I wondered if it was that the query was already being run on the `LoadGrid()` that it was why is doesnt populate. I need a different way of achieving this filter.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into a `List` or `IEnumberable`, you just cannot pass anonymous objects as **datasource** to gridview. `query.ToList();`

You may convert the return type to

```
IEnumerable<object>
```

it can hold any anonymous type and gets easily binded as datasource

Comment: Can you explain this?  [Linq is IEnumerable.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) `The term "LINQ to Objects" refers to the use of LINQ queries with any IEnumerable or IEnumerable<T> collection directly`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I added another property to the anonymous type and that resolved it.

Answer (score -1):

Linq does not support some functionality like .toDays(),.addDays(),.StartsWith() . So what you need to do is,First get the result without using .StartsWith() then try to apply some functionality to filter result StartsWith perticular id.